# MarkLogic Splitting Large XML Files Into Multiple Documents

Tags: xml, split, marklogic, data-ingestion, mlcp

If we have such input file:

```
$ cat > example.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people CREATE_DATE="07/01/2020">
  <person>
    <first>George</first>
    <last>Washington</last>
  </person>
  <person>
    <first>Betsy</first>
    <last>Ross</last>
  </person>
</people>
```

And an ingestion step with mlcp for DHF 5.6

```
$ mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8010 -username user \
    -password password -input_file_path example.xml \
    -input_file_type aggregates -aggregate_record_element person \
    -uri_id last -output_uri_prefix /people/ \
    -output_uri_suffix .xml \
    -transform_module "/data-hub/5/transforms/mlcp-flow-transform.sjs" \
    -transform_param "flow-name=MyFlow,step=1"
```

Is it possible to get the `/people/@CREATE_DATE` during the ingestion for metadata?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is an out-of-the-box way to also snag information from the containing elements surrounding the elements being extracted into individual docs.

Comment: Ok, Mads, thanks for your comment!